# setOnClickListener - application stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android, onclick, buttonclick, application-shutdown

As soon as I use setOnClickListener for a button in my code, when I start the application it says `the application has stopped unexpectedly`

```
package example.khumbayatabbed;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class Category extends ListActivity{
    int categ=0;
    String[] categories = new String[100];
     Button button1;
     EditText edittext1;
       ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
edittext1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
              edittext1.setText("");
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello",
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
          });

       // setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Create a crude view - this should really be set via the layout resources 
        // but since its an example saves declaring them in the XML.

        // Set the text and call the connect function. 
      //call the method to run the data retreival
        final String KEY_121 = "http://myurl";
        getServerData(KEY_121);
        if(mylist.isEmpty())
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No more sub categories",
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
        display(mylist);
    }

    private void getServerData(String jason) {
        mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
       InputStream is = null;
       String returnString="";
       String result = "";
       //mylist.clear();
        //the year data to send
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        //http post
        try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(jason);
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

        //convert response to string
        try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        //parse json data
        try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.i("log_tag","url: "+json_data.getString("url")+
                                ", name: "+json_data.getString("value")
                        );
                        //Get an output to the screen
                        categories[categ++]=json_data.getString("value");
                        map.put("name", json_data.getString("value"));
                        map.put("url", json_data.getString("url"));
                        mylist.add(map);
                        returnString += jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("url") + "\n";
                }

        }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
    }
    private void display(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list)
    {
        ListAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(this,list,R.layout.list_item2, new String[] {"name"}, new int[]{R.id.cat_name});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
     final ListView lv = getListView();
     lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
     lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
         @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
             int position, long id) {
             HashMap<String, String> tmp = new HashMap<String, String>();
             tmp=(HashMap<String, String>)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
             String cat_url=tmp.get("url");
             final String KEY_121 = "http://myurl/"+cat_url;
             getServerData(KEY_121);
             if(mylist.isEmpty())
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No more sub categories",
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
            display(mylist);
         }
       });
        }
}
```

**This is code for my main page:**

```
public class Khumbayatabbed extends TabActivity 
{ /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Category.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("category").setIndicator("Category",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Event.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("event").setIndicator("Event",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
}
```

The main.xml looks like this:

Comment: This code works until i add an onclick event for the button. Even if i add an action listener for the EditText it says application has stopped unexpectedly... Please help.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't wrtie setContentView for your layout.So you can't access Your editText1 and same for the button1.
write something like

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

In your Main Page to call this use

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainPage.this,Category.class);
                                        MainPage.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply.. But as you can see in my code i have commented the setContentView(R.layout.main); statement. If i uncomment it, it again says"The application has stopped unexpectedly."The above code is for a class called category. i have the main page from where i call this page.

Comment: This is an activity.How you called this from another Activity.You have to use startActivity and also have to put this Activity Name in the manifest file

Comment: you have to add setContentView(R.layout.main); before bind any weight from the mail.xml file. so use this line before you bind your edit text and if it not solve send then send me error message that are printed in logcat.

Comment: if i uncomment setContentView(R.layout.main) in my code and remove the code corresponding to button and the edittext then the code that worked bfore uncommenting setContentView(R.layout.main). also starts giving the error "The application has stopped unexpectedly."..

Comment: use setContentView(R.layout.main) right after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);